# Preventing JavaScript method from running twice until its execution is over

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've been having an issue with stopping the JQuery from animating twice. (click the button twice really fast for demonstration)

```js
function slider(){
  var margin = parseInt($("#block").css('marginLeft'));
  if(margin<0){$("#block").animate({marginLeft:"+=50%"},1000);}
  else{$("#block").animate({marginLeft:"-=50%"},1000);}
  };

$(document).ready(function(){

  $("#button").click(function(e){
    slider();
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
  });
})
```

```css
#block{
  background-color:red;
  width:40px;
  height:40px;
  margin-left:-20%;
}
#button{
  cursor:pointer;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p id="button"> Click me</p>

<div id="block"></div>
```

Which method is best to use to pause the function until the execution of the animation is finished? So far I've tried using .stopImmediatePropagation(), setTimeout() and some other methods but none of them seem to work. Is my logic flawed or am I just not exposed to the correct functions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can also take a look at jQuery `stop()` and `finish()`. Depending on behavior wanted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass a function to `animate` that runs once the animation is finished. So, you can have a persistent variable like `doneSliding` - when `slider` runs, toggle it `false`, and when the animation completes, toggle it `true`. If `slider` is called when `doneSliding` is still `false`, an animation is in progress, so return immediately:

```js
let doneSliding = true;
function slider() {
  if (!doneSliding) {
    return;
  }
  doneSliding = false;
  var margin = parseInt($("#block").css('marginLeft'));
  $("#block").animate(
    { marginLeft: margin < 0 ? "+=50%" : "-=50%" },
    1000,
    () => {
      doneSliding = true
    }
  );
};

$("#button").click(slider);
```

```css
#block {
  background-color: red;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  margin-left: -20%;
}

#button {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="button"> Click me</p>
<div id="block"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

It's possible to check if the block is being animated using jquery [`is()`](http://api.jquery.com/is/).

The below code uses `$('#block').is(':animated')` and return from the button click event if true.

```js
function slider(){
  var margin = parseInt($("#block").css('marginLeft'));
  if(margin<0){$("#block").animate({marginLeft:"+=50%"},1000);}
  else{$("#block").animate({marginLeft:"-=50%"},1000);}
};

$(document).ready(function(){

  $("#button").click(function(e){
    // check if it's animated and return false
    if ($('#block').is(':animated')) {
      return false;
    }
    slider();
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
  });
})
```

```css
#block{
  background-color:red;
  width:40px;
  height:40px;
  margin-left:-20%;
}
#button{
  cursor:pointer;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p id="button"> Click me</p>

<div id="block"></div>
```